# How to get a list of internal IP addresses of GCE instances

Tags: awk, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a bunch of instances running in GCE.  I want to programmatically get a list of the internal IP addresses of them without logging into the instances (locally).

I know I can run:

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

But are there any flags I can pass to just get the information I want?
e.g.

```
gcloud compute instances list --internal-ips
```

or similar?  Or am I going to have to dust off my sed/awk brain and parse the output?

I also know that I can get the output in JSON using --format=json, but I'm trying to do this in a bash script.

Comment: or awk is probably better

Comment: a small set of example output from `gcloud` and your required output would make it much easier for non-`gcloud` members to help with your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 34):

The simplest way to programmatically get a list of internal IPs (or external IPs) without a dependency on any tools other than `gcloud` is:

```
$ gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)" compute instances list
$ gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list
```

This uses [`--format=value`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) which also requires a [projection](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections) which is a list of [resource keys](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/resource-keys) that select resource data values. For any command you can use `--format=flattened` to get the list of resource key/value pairs:

```
$ gcloud --format=flattened compute instances list
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it comma separated with value attributes ? This one doesn't work: `gcloud --format="value[terminator=","](networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list`

Comment: @AlexCalm1Kov you have double-quotes nested in double-quotes which breaks, so replace the one of the pairs like so: `gcloud --format="value[terminator=','](networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list` or you could also try using `paste` like so: `gcloud --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" compute instances list | paste -d, -s -` which does not leave a spurious trailing comma when there is only one value-- I would consider that case a bug in the previous command.

Comment: To get the internal IP of a single instance: `gcloud compute instances list --format="value(networkInterfaces[0].networkIP)" --filter="name=('INSTANCE-NAME')"`

Answer (score 10):

A few things here.

First gcloud's default output format for listing is not guaranteed to be stable, and new columns may be added in the future.  Don't script against this!

The three output modes are three output modes that are accessible with the format flag, --format=json, --format=yaml, and format=text, are based on key=value pairs and can scripted against even if new fields are introduced in the future.

Two good ways to do what you want are to use JSON and the jq tool,

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=json \
    | jq '.[].networkInterfaces[].networkIP'
```

or text format and grep + line-oriented using tools,

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=text \
    | grep '^networkInterfaces\[[0-9]\+\]\.networkIP:' | sed 's/^.* //g'
```

Comment: I think you need a . in the jq command, eg gcloud compute instances list --format=json | jq '.[].networkInterfaces[].networkIP'

Comment: My answer here is now a bit out of date.  New releases of gcloud provide a lot more control over output formatting, filtering fields, etc.  See    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats for an overview.

Comment: this helped tremendously. 

export PROXY=$(gcloud compute instances list --format=text     | grep '^networkInterfaces\[[0-9]\+\]\.networkIP:' | sed 's/^.* //g')

will save it to an env variable for you

Answer (score 4):

I hunted around and couldn't find a straight answer, probably because efficient tools weren't available when others replied to the original question. GCP constantly updates their libraries & APIs and we can use the filter and projections to extract targeted attributes.

Here I outline how to reserve an external static IP, see how it's attributes are named & organised, and then export the external IP address so that I can use it in other scripts (e.g. assign this to a VM instance or authorise this network (IP address) on a Cloud SQL instance.

**Reserve a static IP in a region of your choice**

```
gcloud compute --project=[PROJECT] addresses create [NAME] --region=[REGION]
```

**[Informational] View the details of the regional static IP that was reserved**

```
gcloud compute addresses describe [NAME] --region [REGION] --format=flattened
```

**[Informational] List the attributes of the static IP in the form of key-value pairs**

```
gcloud compute addresses describe [NAME] --region [REGION] --format='value(address)'
```

**Extract the desired value (e.g. external IP address) as a parameter**

```
export STATIC_IP=$(gcloud compute addresses describe [NAME] --region [REGION] --format='value(address)’)
```

**Use the exported parameter in other scripts**

```
echo $STATIC_IP
```

Answer (score 1):

The best possible way would be to have readymade `gcloud` command use the same as and when needed.

This can be achieved using `table()` format option with `gcloud` as per below:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format='table(id,name,status,zone,networkInterfaces[0].networkIP :label=Internal_IP,networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP :label=External_IP)'
```

**What does it do for you?**

- Get you data in clean format
- Give you option to add or remove columns

**Need additional columns? How to find column name even before you run the above command?**

Execute the following, which will give you data in raw JSON format consisting value and its name, copy those names and add them into your table() list. :-)

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=json
```

**Plus Point:** This is pretty much same syntax you can tweak with any GCP resources data to fetch including with `gcloud, kubectl` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't filter on specific fields in the gcloud tool.
Something like this will work for a Bash script, but it still feels a bit brittle:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=yaml | grep "  networkIP:" | cut -c 14-100
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Christiaan. Currently there is no automated way to get the internal IPs using the gcloud command.

You can use the following command to print the internal IPs (4th column):

```
gcloud compute instances list | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $4}'
```

or the following one if you want to have the pair `<instance_name> <internal_ip>` (1st and 4th column)

```
gcloud compute instances list | tail -n+2 | awk '{print $1, $4}'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this does not work if you have a network with preemptible instances (in which case the 4th column is whether it's preemptible).