# gcloud compute addresses list returns 0 results although I have external ephemeral addresses

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have one google compute instance in my project with an external IP.
A describe command on the instance shows me:

```
networkInterfaces:
- accessConfigs:
  - kind: compute#accessConfig
    name: External NAT
    natIP: xx.yyy.nnn.mmm
    networkTier: PREMIUM
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
  fingerprint: hjhjhjhjh=
  kind: compute#networkInterface
  name: nic0
  network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/foo-201800/global/networks/default
```

However, when I run on the cloudshell.

```
$ gcloud config get-value project
Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-xxxx]
foo-201800

$ gcloud compute addresses list
Listed 0 items.

$ gcloud compute addresses list --global
Listed 0 items.

$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 215.0.0
...snipped...
```

Are external ephemeral IP addresses not counted in the `gcloud compute addresses` execution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ‘gcloud compute addresses’ command only counts static IP addresses assigned in a project. More specifically, you can read in the summary of the command the following description:

- ['gcloud compute addresses list'](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/list): lists summary information of addresses in a project.

In the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#externaladdresses) about the compute engine IP addresses the definition about the static IP external address and the ephemeral IP address says the following:

- Static external IP addresses are assigned to a project
- Ephemeral external IP addresses are available to VM instances and forwarding rules.

The ephemeral IP are attached to a resources but not a project, when you use the command ‘gcloud compute addresses’ you are only listing the IP attached in a project; the static external IP.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994033/how-to-get-a-list-of-internal-ip-addresses-of-gce-instances) you have an example to list the different types of IP address.

――