# Google cloud instance not accessible by External IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud VM instance which is basically created by a marketplace service 'Elasticsearch Certified by Bitnami'. I cannot access it publically via External IP. I allowed HTTP and HTTPS traffic from the firewall as well.

I can connect it via ssh but not from HTTP. After some research, I came to know that my instance is only accessible from the localhost(127.0.0.1) but I could not figure out how can I make it to be accessed publically.

I ran the `netstat -antup` command and the following is the result. From which I came to know about the localhost(127.0.0.1) only:

[image: Result of netstat -antup command]

I have another instance that is working fine. I can access that via HTTP but not this one, don't know why.

The instance that is working fine, I compared it with this and the only difference that I could figure out is that the correct instance is listening to port 9200 allowed for all. Screenshot below:

[image: Correct index ports listening]

PS: My application is running on port 9200(I can access via ssh login and able to run curl from the server itself)

I created a Firewall Rule to enable port 9200 for all. Which is below:

[image: Firewall Rule for 9200 port]

Following are the Firewall Rules that are applicable to my instance:

[image: Firewall Rules]

I checked all the similar questions here as well but not been able to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated. If need more information regarding this, I will provide that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh is port 22. If you want to access through http and https you have to allow ports 80 and 443 (tcp)

Note that 127.0.0.1 is not your external IP address, you will have to [reserve a static external ip](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

Also if your instance has been restarted then a new ephemeral ip is assigned:

> Ephemeral external IP addresses remain attached to a VM instance only until the VM is stopped and restarted or the instance is terminated. If an instance is stopped, any ephemeral external IP addresses that were assigned to the instance are released back into the general Compute Engine pool and become available for use by other projects. When a stopped instance is started again, a new ephemeral external IP address is assigned to the instance.

Comment: Yes, 127.0.0.1 is for the localhost. I allowed HTTP and HTTPS from Firewall already, isn't that the same?. Do you mean to create new Firewall Rules with 80 and 443 allowed? For external IP, I have ephemeral External IP.

Comment: what is the output of gcloud compute addresses list

Comment: I am new to GCP. I did ran 'gcloud compute addresses list' command in the cloud shell and got 'Listed 0 items.' in response. This was for the whole project which is having two instances. Out of these only one instance is having this issue.

Comment: No worries! Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281989/gcloud-compute-addresses-list-returns-0-results-although-i-have-external-ephemer/53650099

Comment: Thank you for the link. But it says that the google compute address list only counts static IP addresses, not ephemeral External IPs which is true in my case. I do not have any static IP bound to the project.  I just have ephemeral External IP only. Maybe in the future, I have a static IP but for now, I wanted to stic with ephemeral IP.

Comment: Check my edit, make sure the current ephemeral id is the same that the one you try to access?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I haven't stopped or restarted the instance.

Comment: What are your exact firewall rules? https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls did you allow traffic from any IP? Could you try open port 80 and 443 from any IP? Also you may need an index.html (hello world) to make it work

Comment: For the Direction of traffic, choose ingress and egress

Comment: Yes, I created a Firewall rule allow all traffic in ingress by IP range 0.0.0.0/0 for TCP port:9200. As I already allowed HTTP and HTTPS traffic to port 80 and 443 is already open.

Comment: I edited my question with the difference that I could figure out between a correctly working instance and a current bad instance. Maybe this could clear my scenario.

Comment: Port 9200 is for elastic search, I dont see the relationship with ports 80 and 443

Comment: Can you try `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443` and tell me the output? From your instance.

Comment: This 'sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443' returns nothing

Comment: The other instance that is working perfectly also returns nothing by that command 'sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :443'

Comment: have you tried to allow 9200 for all on the other instance? I think what you are looking for is to access through elastic search

Comment: Firewall rule at 9200 port applied only to that specific instans  but nonluck. Yes I am trying to access for elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you Anotnin GAVREL for your time and help. I really appreciate that. I am able to resolve the issue. The issue was with my application's elasticsearch not with the VM instance. My application is binded to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost not to all the network interfaces. 

Again thanks for your time.

Comment: I have a VM on gcp with some external IP address also.. I am not able ssh into that via cloud shell.. am I missing something on firewall rules

Answer (score 2):

So in order to access VMs using external IP, you need to have following

1. External IP attached to your virtual machine, It can be ephemeral or Static IP. Like Below

[image: Compute engine virtual machine]

You can attach an external IP to the VM by selecting the IP as highlighted in the screenshot below

[image]

2. Assuming the application is already running locally on 9023 port in this VM, you need to allow `tcp` traffic on port 9023 in the firewall rule  to the destination VM. After allowing the traffic in the rules, it will look like below -

[image: tcp:9023 highlighted in the picture]

and then you should be able to access `http://<externalIP>:9023/` e.g. http://35.184.142.145:9023/

I just did this for nginx server running on port 9023, same can be done for any application running on any port.

Comment: All the above-mentioned points are done but still no luck. I edited my question with a screenshot of the firewall rule to enable my application's port 9200.

Comment: Are you able to curl the application using the InternalIP of the VM from cloud shell. i.e. http://<internal-ip>:9200 ?

Comment: No. I cannot access it from cloud shell, it says 'Connection timed out'. But I can access the application via ssh login. 'curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200'. I think the issue is that the application is only accessible from localhost not publically.

Comment: Thank you @saurab_garg for your time and help. I really appreciate that. I am able to resolve the issue. The issue was with my application's elasticsearch not with the VM instance. My application is binded to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost not to all the network interfaces. Again thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by these steps:

- Go to `VPC Network` -> `IP Addresses`
- Click on the *three dots* of external IP address that is attached to your VM
- Click on `Promote to static IP address`
- set a name like `test` and submit

Now your IP should be accessible.

Hope it helps you.